# How to set sys.argv in a boost::python plugin

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, boost-python

I use `boost::python` to integrate Python into a C++ program. Now I would like that the Python program that is executed via `boost::python::exec_file()` can obtain the command line arguments of my C++ program via `sys.argv`. Is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify: "set `sys.argv`" vs "obtain the command line" -- you want to read or write to this name?

Comment: I want that the Python code obtains the C++ commandline in `sys.argv`, i.e., if I write in Python `print sys.argv` then it should print the arguments of the C++ program that loads the Python program with `boost::python::exec_file()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to your call to `exec_file()` (but after `Py_Initialize()`, you should invoke `PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);` giving it the `int argc` and `const char *argv[]` from your program's `main()`.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing is that I needed to strdup() all strings and also pass a char** to this function because the Python API wants to get ownership of all these pointers to free them. But then it works, even though it feels very ugly in C++ to do such a thing.